# Massive screen glitch - only cursor and terminal display correctly

Tags: graphics, display, thinkpad

I just got a ThinkPad T60, using my Ubuntu 20.04 installation USB, I was able to successfully install Ubuntu onto the ThinkPad's new SSD without any problems.

Now that I'm trying to log in, the graphics are displaying slashed across the screen! The cursor displays perfectly no matter where I am on the screen, and the ThinkPad's BIOS boots, and the installation USB had no graphical errors. The boot screen on both the ThinkPad BIOS and Ubuntu work perfectly, but the screen is graphically unreadable after Ubuntu boots, the cursor can interact with the elements on the screen as well.

Screen error:

[image: Ubuntu boot]

Ubuntu boot screen:

[image: screen error]

Boot video:

[image: full boot video]

Comment: You didn't mention what media you installed with?  Was the *live* system looking good?  (ie. what kernel was used by your *unstated* 20.04 installation media) as switching kernel stack maybe an easy *fix*.  Does it boot correctly if you use the kernel of your installation media (is that selectable at `grub` during boot?)

Comment: @guiverc The installation media works perfect on this Thinkpad and my regular desktop as a live system. I can boot into my installation media without an issue, it's only booting from a non-live media that causes the screen glitch. Could you tell me how to switch the kernel stack?

Comment: I also want to add that I tested booting into a live system (TAILS), and the same results ensued. Boot up works fine, cursor looks and works fine, but elements on screen are scattered and stretched across. Again, the mouse can interact with the elements on screen, but they are all unreadable.

Comment: Please be specific; Ubuntu 20.04 is available with many ISOs, desktop, server, 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, etc.. I'm guessing 20.04.5 Desktop but it's best if we're told.  You maybe able to select the kernel found on your installation media at boot (Grub menu before Linux has loaded; look in Advanced options); you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details on kernel stack (GA or 4.15 on 20.04 & 20.04.1, various HWE kernels on later media controlled by the .2 (4.18), .3 (5.0), .4 (5.3), .5 (5.4) though HWE kernels will upgrade to latest HWE which is 5.4 for post-install

Comment: If you're using GA, it'll remain 4.15 for the life of the product; but your 20.04 media dictated the kernel on *live* boot & the fallback. If you enabled closed-source you may have also run proprietary kernel modules (drivers) that don't interact well with your hardware, I'd look (text terminal should be readable; `sudo lshw -C display` will list-hardware of class display & show details; driver= shows the kernel module in use)